# How to use a current-controlled voltage source in LTspice for simulation?

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I am trying to simulate a circuit (see below), but it shows an error, stating "unknown controlling source 0". What should I do to get rid of this error?

[image]

This is the circuit that I wish to simulate. I plan to make use of LTspice for the simulation. As you can see in the circuit, there is a current-controlled voltage source.

[image]

How should I connect it? This is what I followed on YouTube, but it failed to simulate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K46tIRUFT8g&t=3s

Comment: I see no problem, at all. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/casEH.png).

Comment: @jonk, are you able to figure out which part I set up wrongly, because from your image, the parameters are same.

Comment: No, not really. I just did my own thing. And it worked. So I really don't know what you did that caused that error.

Comment: @jonk, may you show me your component attribute editor for both dependent voltage sources?

Comment: For [H1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F04Gp.png). What other one do you want? (The 0 V "Vzero" isn't dependent. But this is [its case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2tXr.png), too.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the picture for Vzero. My problem has been solved with appreciation.

Comment: The error tells you that you renamed the reference designator (`Vnnn`, where `nnn` is some number) to `0` (zero), and the value (default `V`) to `Vzero`. The H source is well used, but the controlling source is wrongly named, that's why it complains that it can't find `0` (it searches for a ref. des. named 0). You can solve it in two ways: either make the CCVS have the value `0 5`, which would also be wrong, the error log will pop up saying *unknown parameter Vzero*, but it will work, or do it properly and switch the ref. des. with the value in what would be `Vzero`.